# How do I return to 20.04?

Tags: upgrade, themes

Against my better judgment, I upgraded to 22.04.1 rather than doing a clean install, and now my system has a few problems:

- gthumb crashes trying to play videos;
- Caja will not display icons when accessing my Android phone, which makes it impossible to download an individual photo because Android Gallery (one of the lamest apps ever) will not display filenames;
- My FreeCad files (from an appimage, manually integrated) no longer display the proper icon; and
- it replaced the desktop "theme" with the Yaru icons & theme, which I consider to be truly awful.

How do I revert to 20.04 "Focal Fossa" where everything actually worked like it is supposed to?

Comment: Please re-check your question. You upgraded "*to 20.04.1*" which is not a fully-upgraded system, 20.04.5 is the current state of 20.04, either way you want to return to 20.04?  That makes no sense given 20.04 is the only release you mention.  Either way, restoring your backups made before the upgrade is the easiest option (*Ubuntu tools upgrade to later products, not backwards to earlier ways as that's done via restoration of backups*)

Comment: Sorry, I meant 22.04.1 - my system just said a new version is available, do you want to upgrade? So I did.   Almost every time I did that in the past there were problems but, like a fool I thought this time would be different.

Comment: I have backups of my data but not of the whole system (unless the upgrade process made one).
Caja now has a link to "revert to previous version". What will that do??

Comment: If there are errors in your question, please correct it, and answers/suggestions will be on your actual question itself; comments are for us to ask details with the comments being removed once the details are addressed (ie. you're still asking about a 20.04 system being returned to 20.04 which makes little/no sense)

Comment: FYI:  I'm heavily involved in QA (*Quality Assurance*) of Ubuntu desktop systems (inc. *flavors*) and somewhat regularly re-install using what I think of as *upgrade via re-install* which allows you to change version (*best using same release as you describe, or going to a later release*). It's not intended for use with server systems, or desktop systems with server apps (*which store configs in system directories*) but you re-use existing partitions without format to trigger this install type. It may not cope with 3rd party software though as it's not intended to.

Comment: I understand why this question got downvoted, but I don't agree. There are operating systems that let you downgrade soon after an upgrade (cough, cough, Windows), so it's not an unheard-of feature. And there are legitimate reasons for people to want to do things like that. Just the fact that someone's asking how to do something that can't be done doesn't mean they deserve downvotes, it means they need to know that it can't be done and what can be done instead.

Comment: guiverc - what do you means by "upgrade via re-install"? Is that a new command?

Comment: Lubuntu refer to it as *install using existing partition* and it's documented [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) but do note that documentation was geared at QA-testers & not end-users. It's also written about ~30 times on this site too, but my searches mostly pull up references to it & not the ~3 answers where it's mentioned. It's not intended for Ubuntu Server installs or server apps (where config/conf can be in system directories that get erased), or 3rd party apps; and going backwards check apps can deal with datafiles from newer vers.

Comment: I tried to clean install 22.04.1 along side the existing installation but cfdisk did not redo the partitions correctly and I lost everything do I ended up wiping the whole disk and doing a clean install of 22.04.1. The problems listed above are still there so I guess they are inherent to 22.04.1. I will ask for help on fixing them in separate inquiries.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to downgrade to 20.04, you'll have to back up your data, wipe your system, and reinstall from scratch. [Link to 20.04.05 for your convenience](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.5/)

As long as you're doing a clean install, I'll suggest going with version 22.04.01. Starting over with a clean slate may solve the problems you're seeing. [Link to 22.04.01 for your convenience](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: I'll second the idea of reinstalling 22.04 from scratch. My experience with upgrading wasn't so good. A fresh install usually works better and runs faster.

Comment: @kanehekili I upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04 out of sheer laziness and got lucky. No trouble whatsoever. I wasn't going to push it this time, though, and I'm happier with a clean 22.04.01.